# Green's function/resolvent of the hydrogen hamiltonian

Tags: mathematical-physics, research-level, hydrogen, greens-functions, propagator

Let $H$ be the Hamiltonian for the nonrelativistic hydrogen atom, i.e.
$$H=-\frac{1}{2}\Delta-\frac{1}{r}$$

I am searching for an asymptototic expansion of the Greens function or respectively the resolvent operator acting on some function. I think the Greens function has to be some kind of confluent hypergeometric function, however, I am not able to calculate it, neither did I find anything useful on the internet. Does anyone know the Greens function or the asymptotic expansion or hasat least has an idea where I can find it?

Also, related question on MO: [Asymptotic decay for the inhomogeneous Schrödinger equation](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/181403/asymptotic-decay-for-the-inhomogeneous-schr%C3%B6dinger-equation)

Comment: I know it is a very mathematical reference, but I think you should find some useful properties of asymptotic expansions of resolvents on the book by [Kato](http://www.amazon.com/Perturbation-Theory-Operators-Classics-Mathematics/dp/354058661X). (you may find some pdf version online)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know his works, unfortunately, he only covers the homogeneous case ("Growth Properties of Solutions of the Reduced Wave Equation With a Variable Coefficient"), not the resolvents.

Comment: Are you sure? There is asymptotic perturbation theory of the resolvents on the book (that is more recent than your cited article), I checked (it is on Chapter 8, because the resolvent of the operator you need is not compact).

Comment: Well, there is of course a high probability that I just overlooked it because dumbness. I will read the paper more carefully asap, thank you for making me aware of this :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is all over the place, but it's involved. It is normally calculated from the path integral propagator. The most concise source of the radial Green's function you are after is eqn (15) of [Grosche 1998](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0031-8949/57/6/001/pdf), in terms of modified Bessel functions, integral rep,
 $$
  G_l^C(r'',r';E)  
   = \int_0^\infty\dfrac{e^{i e^2s''/\hbar}ds''}{\sqrt{v'v''}}  
  \dfrac{m\omega\sqrt{v'v''}}{i\hbar\sin\omega s''}
  \exp\bigg[\dfrac{i m\omega}{2\hbar}({v'}^2+{v''}^2)\cot\omega s''\bigg] 
  I_{2l+1}\bigg(\dfrac{m\omega v'v''}{i\hbar\sin\omega s''}\bigg)
   $$
linked to parabolic coordinates and streamlining, essentially, eqn (109) of [Duru & Kleinert's 1982](http://users.physik.fu-berlin.de/~kleinert/83/83.pdf) path integral-derived answer. Nobody said they are not messy. The integral can further be reduced to Whittaker functions *M* and *W*, [Khandekar & Lawande 1986](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0370157386900293) eqns (7.2.8) and finally (7.2.15).